# std::queue::size() can return a huge number after pop() of size() == 0

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

I have the link here where I `push(x)` 10 `int`s, then `pop()` 11 and the size is not 0, or an exception, but a tremedous number (probably `== std::numeric_limit<size_type>::max()`). I assume this is the consequence of the internal representation simply doing a `size--` and not checking for an already `empty()` case. This seems like a bug in the stdc++ library.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27ae7f10855e6c23

Comment: Welcome to the world of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Don't pop more than you have pushed.

Comment: The bug is you calling `pop()` on an empty container...

Answer (score 10):

It's called "Undefined behaviour". To save time in the implementation (not checking if it's already empty), the implementation will simply decrement despite there being "nothing to decrement". Don't do that (and on another implementation it may not do that, so definitely don't rely on it doing anything meaningful). Since it's undefined, it may also dial out to Australia on your modem, erase your hard-disk or cause the application to crash. Or something else...

Comment: [Some people are hilariously scared of an "if" statement](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55841).  This is why we have branch predictors.

Comment: But it's completely unnecessary - and if you check, what are you going to do? Throw an exception? Just ignore the `pop()`? Phone Australia on the modem, since the stupid programmer deserves that? ;) [Even with branch predictors, it's a fair bit of overhead - and it "throws out some other entry" in the branch cache...]

Comment: @Aggieboy branches are not for free, and reporting errors isn't either. Try accessing elements of a vector with the `at()` member and with `operator[]` and see.

Comment: What if UB caused your code to post a SO question blaming the Standard Library?

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Entirely within the scope of UB, and if you are writing a web-app for interfacing to SO, maybe even quite plausible... :) [And how do we know this isn't what has happened, and the universe got replaced with a more complex one?]

Comment: @juanchopanza Then at the very least, they should provide a safer `pop` that is synonymous to vector's `add`.

Comment: @Aggieboy: Who's to say that isn't the case, if you build with debug enabled?

Comment: They could have done this internally: `size -= !empty();` and relied on a bool to int promotion, and no branches. It would seem that this is a bad place to put undefined behavior, since it's clearly nonsensical to cause an effect to the queue (alter the size) when it's already empty.

Comment: Yes, but how do you know that `empty()` in itself isn't an if? It is wrong to call `pop()` on an empty container object, just as it's wrong to divide an integer by zero or access an invalid pointer or leave out the termination in a C-string and then call a library function that processes the string. All undefined behaviour is undefined, fixing one single container doesn't really fix the fact that you need to understand what you are doing in C and C++, and don't have much of a "safety net".

Answer (score 4):

It is incorrect to `pop` an empty `queue`.  Doing so means what happens is not defined by the standard, and most implemetations (in release/optimized builds) simply do broken things and do not check.

If you need a safe pop, try:

```
template<class Q>
void safe_pop(Q&q){
  if (!q.empty())
    q.pop();
}
```

and use `safe_pop(que);` instead of `que.pop();`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably queue size data member gets decremented in `pop()` even if the queue is empty. Most likely the size data member has an unsigned integer type, when you decrement an unsigned zero it just wraps around to the biggest representable value.

EDIT: confirmed, 18446744073709551615 is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF hexadecimal, which is the biggest value that can be represented by 8 bytes.

Comment: Also, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF as a signed 64-bit integer is really -1.  So yeah, it's basically zero decremented.  But as others have noted, the real answer is that popping from an empty STL container is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When you pop 1 more than push, internally you get size -1. However size_t is unsigned so -1 get typecasted to (unsigned max long - 1). However there is no intention to "fix" this issue because it will add an extra check in code and might cause performance issue. Unlike managed languages, C++ developers don't want anything extra that might cause even slight performance degradation :).

Here's related thread for GCC:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55841